# How do I connect to Firebird through Visual Studio 2019 and C#

Tags: c#, android, database, visual-studio, flamerobin

I am struggling to connect to a Firebird database in C# through Visual Studio 2019
I was able to connect to the database through FlameRobin, but I don't really know how to connect through Visual Studio 2019 and C#.

Please show me all the commands I need to enter to connect and to insert data
I installed FirebirdSql.Dtaba.FirebirdClient
I tried so many codes, but it all failed

[FlameRobin Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nef78.png)

[The code I used to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHcpU.png)

Comment: Please share one of your failed attempts, its easier to tell you what went wrong, and share the error message you are receiving.

Comment: This is the error I get when I try to connect:  W/ompanyname.scan(13297): type=1400 audit(0.0:108): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[97506]" dev="sockfs" ino=97506 ioctlcmd=10 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c91,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c91,c256,c512,c768 tclass=tcp_socket permissive=0

Comment: @RandRandom I also added the code I used to connect. Not sure if I used it properly.

Comment: Since you tagged your question with android can I assume you are running this code on the android emulator or on an android phone? If thats the case, an obvious error is that your database file on `C:\ProgramData\xxx.fdb` is most likely wrong. Since my android knowledge is basically non existent I can't help you further.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am running it on android emulator. I am not sure what do you mean by the database file is wrong. I am able to see the database file in that directory. Anyway, thank you for your time. hopefully, someone can help me

Comment: IMHO - The android emulator won't have access to your local machine file system, I am assuming that your drive `C:\ ` is a local drive on your PC and not on the android system. Also, the `localhost` wouldn't resolve to your PC but to your android system, and I doubt that the firebird server is running on the phone, instead most likely you have firebird installed on your pc, so instead of localhost you would need to use the IP of your PC and make sure that the android emulator has access to your PC. But than again, as I mentioned, I am week with android so I could say bullshit.

Comment: Actually, that helped. I am making progress. Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.